# How do i increase the font size of Name column under div Greater Quantity

Tags: css

I am trying to increase the font size of the Name column present under div Greater Quantity

I have tried as following but its not reflecting

```
<div class="first">
<h1>Greater Quantity</h1>
    <div  id="greaterquan"></div>
</div>

#greaterquan {
  float:left;
  background-color:purple;
   font-size: 14px;
         font-color: white  ;
}
```

Could you please let me know how to do this

http://jsfiddle.net/b4j852uq/6/

Comment: `#greaterquan .sorting_1` should help.

Answer (score 1):

Like this? [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b4j852uq/7/)

```
#greaterquan .sorting_1{
    font-size:15px;
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: could you please tell me what does sorting_1 mean ??